# Swift 3: Google Maps Api not changing camera view

Tags: xcode, google-maps, swift3

Hey so I'm trying to change the location of the map camera though a method, however when I run the program nothing happens.

```
func SearchConfirmed (d1: Double, d2: Double){

    print(d1 , " ", d2)
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: d1, longitude: d2, zoom: 15)
    mapView?.animate(to: camera)

}
```

When this method is called it is able to print the lat and lng but it doesn't change the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, because I was calling it from another method, it created an instance of this view controller and changed the view in the instance. However because I was not displaying the instance nothing happened. To solve it I just ran all the code in the view controller and didn't call the method from another place.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `GMSCameraUpdate` after create a map

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: firstLtd, longitude: firstLng, zoom: zoomScale)
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
```

When you want the update camera position;

```
let newCoor = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (newLtd)!, longitude: (newLng)!)
 let newCoorCam = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(newCoor)
 mapView?.animate(with: newCoorCam)
```

Comment: I've done that too but still when I try to change my location after once. The problem I think is with the method, because it is getting called form another view controller. When I run the same program though the viewdidLoad it runs fine.